# New patch supee-6788 how to apply patch

Tags: admin, security, patches, supee-6788

After weeks of waiting for the patch today (27.10.2015) it was released: [SUPEE-6788](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details)

A lot of things were patched and also is encouraged to review installed modules for possible vulnerabilities.

I open this post in order to get some insights about how to apply the patch. What are the steps to apply the patch? To my understanding this are the steps:

1. Fix modules with admin functionality that is not under the admin URL
2. Fix modules that use SQL statements as field names or escape fields
3. White list blocks or directives that uses variables like `{{config path=”web/unsecure/base_url”}}` and `{{bloc type=rss/order_new}}`
4. Addressing potential Exploit with Custom Option File Type (no idea how to do this)
5. Apply the patch

Is this the correct procedure?

Comment: Current listed CE versions 1.7.0.0 through 1.9.2.0

Comment: The patch changes `.htaccess.sample` as well as `.htaccess`. The latter is customized in most shops, this will make the patch fail => You need to temporarily replace it with the original file from Magento, apply the patch, restore your own .htaccess and apply the change which protects access to `cron.php` manually (don't use the production system for this process of course!)

Comment: what about those using nginx?

Comment: you probably have the original .htaccess file in place. Just check your nginx configuration to make sure that cron.php cannot be accessed from web

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's no question. Please move discussions [to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25332/magento-chat)

Comment: There is a question in the very title of the post, also in the last paragraph I'm more specific. Regardless this, this sort of post are very useful in my opinion to centralize comments and best practices when applying a newly released patch.

Comment: Then please reword the question and focus on the matter of "how to apply?" specifically instead of a very broad "everything about SUPEE-6788". I'd suggest removing the image too as it doesn't add anything to the question of "how to..."

Comment: @lloiacono The proper place for such a centralized discussion would be the Magento forum. I would however encourage people to use the SUPEE-6788 tag here for questions on specific cases they have trouble solving.

Comment: moved this to meta since there is more of a discussion than a question, but it' still valuable for the community.

Comment: I'd highly recommend checking out this toolbox to help with fixing incompatible modules: https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In general, you can apply the patch as all previous ones. Have a look at the [official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html) and check this [SE post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/63858/142). But yes, there are some additional points you should check when applying this patch. Byte/Hypernode has a [nice post](http://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/how-to-install-magento-patch-supee-6788/) about it.

1. Check if your theme has a custom `template/customer/form/register.phtml` or custom `template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml`. If this is the case, make sure that it includes a `form_key`.
2. Check if your theme has a custom `layout/customer.xml`. If this is the case, make sure to apply the necessary changes from the patch (`customer_account_resetpassword` has been changed to `customer_account_changeforgotten`).
3. Do you use non-standard variables in CMS pages, static blocks or email templates? Then make sure that you whitelist them. See [this SE question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/87897/142) to learn how to whitelist variables/blocks.
4. Do you run the `cron.php` via HTTP? Make sure that you better use `cron.sh`. If this is not possible, at least make sure that you call cron.php via CLI PHP. If for some reason you can not configure a real cronjob and need to run it via HTTP, see [this SE question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/88335/243)
5. Make sure that all your extensions use the "new" admin routing. You can use [this n98-magerun](https://github.com/peterjaap/magerun-addons) plugin to check. You can also use [this CLI script](https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox). You can also have a look at [this related SE question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/87214/142).

   6. When all your extensions use the proper admin routing, make sure to disable "Enable Admin routing compatibility mode" under System - Configuration - Admin - Security.
6. If you use M2ePro, update it to the latest version since old versions do not work with the new patch.

When updating, make sure that you delete the file `dev/tests/functional/.htaccess`. It is not present any more in Magento 1.9.2.2. Keeping it means you are still vulnerable.

In any case, check your page with [MageReport](https://www.magereport.com) after updating to see if everything went well.

There is also a [technical blog post by Piotr](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details), which describes the critical changes.

Comment: Just a little note, the CLI script mentions to 'Verify all is well, then disable the admin controller compatibility mode'. I think they mean the opposite, to enable it. Is that right?

Comment: @kaska If all your extensions are okay, you have to **disable** the compatibility mode.

Comment: in a production environment shouldn't you remove /dev completely?

Comment: @paj theoretically yes. But with version 1.9.2.2, it is protected with a .htaccess, so it should be okay to keep it. Just make sure to follow my .htaccess advise above.

Comment: Thank you for the completeness, they should let you write the condensed release notes next time! Super helpful!

Answer (score 6):

There is a check file which helps you to identify issues:
https://github.com/gaiterjones/magento-appsec-file-check

I made a CLI script out of it.
https://github.com/Schrank/magento-appsec-file-check

Answer (score 3):

For Nginx, make sure you block access to cron.php and the dev folder. We use this block:

```
location ~ ^/(app|includes|media/downloadable|pkginfo|report/config.xml|var|magmi|cron.php|dev)/? { deny all; }
```

Comment: your regex will not work, cause you check against directory only, . so "report/config.xml , cron.php" do not match, and you have a vertical bar or pipe symbol at the end.. copy-paste? also do not mess regex together with /app/ , if you misplace something, it will be hacked.

Comment: Bad copy and paste job, sorry. Added in the ? at the end so the trailing slash is optional. Tested it just now and it is working as it should.

Comment: also this regex is vulnerable, you have ^/ , make sure you dont copy your source files into top folder, like /old/ , /upgrade/ etc

Comment: @MagenX So you're saying that if you don't use version control or standard system administration BCP, that this regex is to blame?

Answer (score 1):

I just applied the patch on my 1.10.1 EE and this causes side effects on native screens because the core is not APPSEC-1063 compliant:

Example:

In `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Entity/Attribute/Collection.php`

You can find 2 `addFieldToFilter` calls not APPSEC-1063 compliant.

This is breaking the Customer > Attribute grids, so you have to patch the patch, using the trick they recommend in the pdf "SUPEE-6788-Technical%20Details%20.pdf" in APPSEC-1063 section

Changing the several

> ```
>     $this->addFieldToFilter($field, 0);
> ```

(where $field contains complex (CASE .. WHEN THEN...) sql statements )

into

> ```
>     $resultCondition = $this->_getConditionSql($field, 0);
>     $this->_select->where($resultCondition);
> ```

Both rhoerr's supee-6788-toolbox and gaiterjones' didn't detect this kind of issues, I checked all the others ->addFieldToFilter($ and none seem to be causing the issue.

Other affected 1.10 core files: (found by rhoerr's supee-6788-toolbox)

```
app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Model/Mysql4/Option/Collection.php
```

There may be more.