# Website not showing after installed supee-6788

Tags: supee-6788, home-page, magento-1.9.1.1

Lately i have tried to install supee-6788 patch for my website.

But that patch is not installing. So, i found one accepted solution from here. That shows, replace .htaccess file with fresh .htaccess file. I have done same as . Now, patch was installed successfully.

Then, suddenly homepage is not showing anything.

My website is : https://www.depoto.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd check `System -> Permissions -> Blocks` and ensure the blocks you're using have a status of `Allowed`.

Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33433109/applying-supee-6788-it-removes-static-block-on-home-page

Comment: Hello Brother, Yes, i have cheked and followed yours , Thanks.

Comment: Hi, https://www.depoto.com/ is not opening. Please check once

Answer (score 0):

This is case in point why it's essential to install security patches on a staging environment prior to porting over to production.

Take the following actions to remedy the situation:

1. [Revert the patch](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html#revert)
2. Clone your production site onto a staging environment
3. Install the patch on the staging environment.
4. Debug until functionality is 100% as expected.

In this instance, it would seem like the product block you're expecting is no longer there due to it not being whitelisted.

Check out these posts for help on that front:

[New patch supee-6788 how to apply patch](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88970/new-patch-supee-6788-how-to-apply-patch/88973#88973)

[APPSEC-1057 How to add variables or blocks to the white list tables](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87466/appsec-1057-how-to-add-variables-or-blocks-to-the-white-list-tables/87897#87897)