# 404error while running cronjob in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I am facing 404 error while running cron from url

http://www.mywebsitesite/cron.php

This shows 404 error . My cron job is not running.

Kindly help to resolve the issue

Comment: check in mageno root cron.php exist or not? If not take it from any default magento setup and try again

Comment: Yes cron.php exists

Comment: I have tried with other cron.php also

Comment: check your htaccess file if any rule for redirect cron to 404 or not

Comment: If this saying 404 then your base url must not be set as "http://www.mywebsitesite/"

Comment: I have checked i found these lines in my htaccess file 

## Deny access to cron.php
    <Files cron.php>

Answer (score 1):

You applied the supee-6788 security patch, which makes calling cron via http invalid.

refer to: [After applying SUPEE-6788 , cron stopped working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88335/after-applying-supee-6788-cron-stopped-working)

I highly suggest you install [AOE Scheduler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler) as it will give you a better view over your crons, and it will also suggest your crontab configuration.