# Access forbidden issue in cron execution magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, localhost, access

I am new in magento 1.9 . I want to run a cron job . I have added the required code in config.xml and make a php file in model folder .I want to run the cron on local host xampp windows. 
When I run it on browser it gaves me access forbidden error. 
In browser I write:

```
http://localhost/project_name/cron.php
```

it gave me that issue.

[image]

Is there some other way to run the cron on local host?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually if you got installed Patches  , this issues display . Check the .htaccess and add the rule for the cronjob , follow [cron issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88335/after-applying-supee-6788-cron-stopped-working/88337#88337) link for more .